# Operator characters in variables stop jQuery targeting

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, variables, operator-keyword

Okay, so this might be a little awkward to explain. 
My function is given an element to target, and takes an ID displayed in the element using innerHTML. That ID also then appears in the name of a class, which must also be targeted. However, the ID has the possibility to contain either "+", "/" or "\" characters, which stop jQuery being able to use the ID in a variable.

Edit: I neglected to mention, when I say ID, this isn't an elemnt ID. It's a user ID, I can target multiple elements with it because it appears in class names as well as on the page.

Here's the code:

```
function goFilt(filtID) {
    var ptbf = document.getElementById("pc" + filtID);
    var ptbfIdc = ptbf.getElementsByClassName("hand");
    var ptbfId = ptbfIdc[0].innerHTML;
    ptbf.className = 'animated hinge';
    setTimeout(function () {
        $q("#pc" + filTar).animate({
            height: "1px"
        }, 500);
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $q("#pc" + filTar).css("display", "none");
    }, 1500);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $q(".id_" + ptbfId).parent().parent().parent().parent().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $q(".id_" + ptbfId).parent().parent().parent().parent().animate({
                height: "1px"
            }, 500);
        }, 500);
    }, 1500);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $q(".id_" + ptbfId).parent().parent().parent().parent().css("display", "none");
    }, 2500);
}
```

So say our ID is VmOR+MU8.
We get that by tageting the element with the class name "hand" and taking the inner html, and we save it as variable ptbfId.
We then need to taget elements with the class id_VmOR+MU8, but we can't use $q(".id_" + ptbfId), because the "+" in the ID stops that working.
That is my problem. Short of a stupid runaround with regex's I can't think how to fix this. The IDs need to be usable after that point too, so if the answer is swapping bad characters for temporary ones, then it would need to be quickly interchangable.

Any help from you guys going?

Edit 2: example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RpVr2/

Comment: A `+` sign is not a valid character in an `id`, anyway. `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").` This is bad design, change it.

Comment: @MasterAM That's not true in HTML5 anymore, see http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: So why don't you keep using getElementById/getElementsByClassName as you did in the first lines (or maybe try querySelect/querySelectorAll), then wrap the resulting elements in jQuery objects?

Comment: @bfavaretto, I stand corrected. But still, I think the overall design is problematic. Since you already preserve scoped variables in the timer callbacks, you can at least give meaningful names to all of those parents and avoid re-selecting the same node altogether.

Comment: @MasterAM I agree with that; and if the unusual/problematic ids can be avoided, better still. All I was saying is that they're not invalid anymore.

Comment: I should have noted, by ID, I don't mean an element ID. The ID is a user ID. What we're working with here are essentially forum threads, and I've got a filter button on every post with a userscript. The ID is the user ID, it shows in the post, and each post also contains a class like "id_userid", basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

escape `+` and `/` with 1 backslash and the backslash with 2 backslashes

Comment: replace wouldn't work because they have the potential to show up more than once. if I were to go down that route i would need global regex's I think, and I'm not sure that would work anyway. I'm trying to use the stored string in a class name, and afaik, escape characters should be read as regular characters. I'm not 100% sure this isn't a jQuery bug rather than just contextually undesirable operation.

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, I'm not sure if it's just me, by I couldn't apply your example in the context of my code. I knocked up a fiddle that is just short of identicle to what I'm actually doing, maybe it will help. http://jsfiddle.net/RpVr2/ Basically, all you need to know, is when you click !! next to an ID, all the containers with that ID should dissappear, but you can see the ones with + in the ID don't. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Turns out escaping works, I'm sorry I was to dense to realise. Another friend helped, we used regex's rather than replace, though your answer was pretty much perfect from the beginning. Thanks!